# C++ friend class data access

Tags: c++

C++ newbie here.

I am a science guy writing a cfd (ish) code. I have created a class for all solving functions, and one that handles operations on a grid. The grid class wants to be able to see a few of the variables stored in the solving class, as passing them all to the grid class seems like a bit of effort.

So in my research I came across friend classes, but can't seem to get it to work. Please see the fully cut back example below. Class A is the solver, and it creates a grid class B. Even though I have written friend class B, I still get the following compile error (g++):

In member function 'void B::testB()':

error: 'a1' was not declared in this scope

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class B {
private:
    int b1;

public:
    void testB(){
        cout<<a1<<endl;
    };  


};

class A {
friend class B;

private:
    int a1;

public:
    void testA(){
        a1=2;
        B b;
        b.testB();
        };
};


int main(){
    A a;
    a.testA();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a1 only exists as a part of *instances* of class A. In other words, you need an A object in order to access a1.

EDIT:
but it turns out that wasn't the only problem in the source you gave.

This works:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B;

class A {
  friend class B;
  private:
    int a1;
  public:
    void testA();
};

class B {
private:
    int b1;

public:
    void testB(A *a){
        cout << (a->a1) << endl;
    }
};

void A::testA() {
    this->a1 = 2;
    B b;
    b.testB(this);
}


int main(){
    A a;
    a.testA();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer is exactly the one I was looking for. My experience with the this pointer was too limited to understand how to get it to work.

However, why would you opt for this->a1 = 2; rather than simply a1=2?

Comment: There's no difference between this-a1 = 2; and a1 = 2; I just like to qualify variables as much as possible. Now, I posted the code I did because it was the closest to what you posted, but what Nawaz posted is a bit better. You should always try to instantiate variables in constructors. It would be even better if you could find a way to avoid a friend class altogether.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you should code this:  (please read the comments!)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A 
{
    friend class B; //this means, B can access private members of A!
private:
    int a1; //private member data

public:
    A (int a) : a1(a) {}
private:
    void testA() //private member function
    {
       cout << a1 << endl;
    }
};

class B {
    int b1;
public:
    void testB()
    {
        A a(100);
        cout<<a.a1<<endl; //B is accessing A's private member data!
        a.testA();        //B is accessing A's private member function!
    }
};    
int main(){
    B b;
    b.testB();
}
```

Online Demo : http://ideone.com/LDEOO

Read these tutorials:

- [Friendship and inheritance](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/) (basic)
- [Friends (C++ only)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr043.htm) (basic)
- [Friend scope (C++ only)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr043.htm) (advanced)

Comment: I see how this works, but the the way you now create B from the main class rather than A has confused me a bit, and I don't now how to change it so that it works for my case.

Comment: @CptLightning: There is nothing confusing. `B` has access to private members of `A`, since `B` is a `friend` of `A`. That is why I created an instance of `B` in main, so that I can demonstrate how B accesses what it has access to!

Comment: @CptLightning: And if you create instance of `A`, then you would call `testA` which in turn would call `testB` so that `B` may have opportunity to access A's private members. This approach is a bit lengthy, as far as demonstrating friendship is concerned. So I avoided it. I don't see any point in calling `testA` from main!

Answer (score 2):

You are confused. `friend`-declarations are useful to gives a class or function access to a classes private or protected members. They are not necessarily what you want here. You probably just want `B` to have a reference to an `A`, like others have suggested:

```
class A;

class B {
public:
    B(A & a) : a(a) {}
private:
    A & a;
};
```

To enable `B` to access private or protected members of `A`, you have two options:

1. Use a public accessor:

   ```
   class A {
   public:
       // You can also make this function returns a const reference
       int getItem() const { return item; }
   private:
       int item;
   };
   ```

   This way you do not need a friend declaration.
2. Use a `friend` declaration.

You may want to read [what the C++FAQ-Lite has to say about this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/friends.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply an object of which a1. Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
friend class B;

private:
    int a1;

public:
    void testA();
};

class B {
private:
    int b1;

public:
    void testB(A &a){
        cout<<a.a1<<endl;
    }  
};

void A::testA(){
    a1=2;
    B b;
    b.testB(*this);
}


int main(){
    A a;
    a.testA();
}
```

Comment: Type A is unknown until its definition. It will not compile.

Comment: You need to forward declare `class A`

Comment: Actually you need to do far more then forward declare class A. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of class `B` to access its members. Try

```
void testB(B *b){
    cout << b->a1 << endl;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

class B;

class A
{
friend class B;

private:
    int a1;

public:
    void testA();
};
#endif
```

B.h

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include <iostream>

#include "A.h"

class B
{
private:
    int b1;

public:
    void testB(A &a)
    {
        std::cout << a.a1 << std::endl;
    }
};
#endif
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

void A::testA()
{
    a1 = 2;
    B b;
    b.testB(*this);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.testA();
}
```

`g++ main.cpp A.cpp -o test`

`./test`

prints:

`2`

Pieces of advice:

- Try to divide your programs into many
  files, like I did. Headers and definitions should go in separate ones. It simplifies
  debugging, reading, using etc.
- Never use `using` inside header
  files.

Comment: Thanks, the way you describe is the format of my actual code, I changed it to the super compact version for my post. I can avoid doing this in future if this is not the norm.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you're working on CFD, I think this question is on the wrong path. You should probably use something like Eigen / Lapack / Vtk libraries and follow the style there. Perhaps you can say why you need friend functions for interacting with your grid?

My similar tale: before I was good enough with c++, it was hard to make sense of big libraries and I wrote stuff like in your question. Now I reuse what's out there and only code the low level math stuff for new functionality. I suspect you're in a similar situation.

Comment: Thanks, it's not technically cfd, that's just the term I would use with a lay person. I'm doing a more simple vortex lattice method, and it is easier for me to code the basic grid operations myself. However, I do use Lapack as you suggest for my solving.